# mailto: anchor links unloading html5 video in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I have a very simple page with a `<video>` tag and an email anchor link:
http://jsfiddle.net/6GquX/3/

Clicking the email link in Chrome (OS X 10.8 + Win7, 23.0.1271.97) invokes the `beforeunloadchange` event and causes the video to unload, which isn't the desired outcome.

Curiously enough, if I let the video buffer a bit and then click the email link, the video keeps playing and doesn't unload.

To my knowledge this only occurs in Chrome and I'm truly at a loss. Visiting any HTML5 video player site (videojs, flowplayer etc), starting a HTML5 video and then immediately simulating an email click with `document.location.href = "mailto:foo@bar.com"` in the dev console yields the same error.

However, I'm inclined to think it's the way in which the video has been encoded as I'm unable to recreate the above with a video downloaded from YouTube's HTML5 player:
http://jsfiddle.net/6GquX/4/ ([source](http://www.youtube.com/embed/WkfgL5P3fw4?html5=1&autoplay=1&vq=medium))

**1. Is it possible that YouTube are encoding their videos in a particular way to combat this?**
**2. Are there any strategies / hacks I can employ to get around this?**

**Update:**

The issue seems to be linked to the bitrate of the video. Re-encoding that flowplayer example above to 300kbps resolves the issue. (A 400kbps video still exhibits the same issue, not sure what the exact threshold is)

300kbps example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6GquX/7/

Hopefully this will be resolved in a future version of Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered the bug you seem to be describing myself.
My workaround was to simply play the video again after someone clicks the mailto link.

```
$('.email').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            // video.js handle (insert whatever call you want to play the video)
            _V_.players.video.play();
        },
        2000
    );
});
```

Comment: An alternative (and less elegant / user friendly) solution would be to simply add target="_blank" to all email anchor tags.